# Unit test for equality incl. NaNs

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, equality

I am doing some tests using the `matlab.unittest` framework. I need to compare to arrays which are indeed identical. However, they comprise some `NaN` values (at the same locations). Now, if you issue the command `isequal(NaN,NaN)`, the result will be false as `NaNs` are per definition not equal. That implies that my test fails when using the `verifyEqual` command.

How am I supposed to test two arrays for equality using the unit test framework, when these arrays are indeed identical but comprise some `NaN` values?

Comment: How about [isequaln](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequaln.htmll)?

Comment: Or if you need element-wise comparison: `a==b|(isnan(a)&isnan(b))`

Comment: @Zep `isequaln` is producing the correct result using the command line. However, I need to incorporate this test into a unit test class. Right now, I am using `verifyEqual`, such as `testCase.verifyEqual(actual, expected)` - Not sure how to incorporate `isequaln`!

Comment: I have never used matlab.unittest, but it looks like this dirty workaround could work: `testCase.verifyEqual(isequaln(a,b), true)`

Comment: @Zep This indeed solves the problem!! Thanks.

Comment: Improvement: `testCase.verifyTrue(isequaln(a,b))`

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT***
Currently timetables are indeed using `isequal` rather than `isequaln`. However we are looking into favoring the use of `isequaln` over `isequal` by default for a future version of MATLAB.

In the meantime, your current workaround would work, but the following two approaches might get you better diagnostics:

1. First convert the timetables to tables. When it fails you will get better diagnostics which actually point to the part of your timetable which fails. This will also allow you to apply tolerances to the values of the timetables. One drawback, the diagnostics will show them as tables rather than what they really are - timetables.

   ```
   >> testCase.verifyEqual(timetable2table(actual), timetable2table(actual));
   Interactive verification failed.

   ---------------------
   Framework Diagnostic:
   ---------------------
   verifyEqual failed.
   --> Path to failure: <Value>.Data
       --> The values are not equal using "isequaln".
       --> Failure table:
               Index    Actual    Expected    Error    RelativeError
               _____    ______    ________    _____    _____________

                 1        50         20        30           1.5     
                 2        50         20        30           1.5     

       Actual double:
           50
           50
       Expected double:
           20
           20

   Actual Value:
     2×2 table

               Time            Data
       ____________________    ____

       20-Oct-2017 00:00:00     50 
       21-Oct-2017 00:00:00     50 
   Expected Value:
     2×2 table

               Time            Data
       ____________________    ____

       20-Oct-2017 00:00:00     20 
       21-Oct-2017 00:00:00     20 
   >>
   ```
2. Use `verifyReturnsTrue` and call isequaln directly. This at least shows the function handle used to compare the values when it fails

   ```
   testCase.verifyReturnsTrue(@() isequaln(actTimeTable, expTimeTable));
   ```

In the verifyReturnsTrue case, if you still want to see the actual and expected tables in failure diagnostics, you can pass them in as test diagnostics. This looks like the following:

```
import matlab.unittest.diagnostics.Diagnostic;
>> testCase.verifyReturnsTrue(@() isequaln(actual, expected),...
    Diagnostic.join(actual, expected))
Interactive verification failed.

----------------
Test Diagnostic:
----------------
  2×1 timetable

            Time            Data
    ____________________    ____

    20-Oct-2017 00:00:00     50 
    21-Oct-2017 00:00:00     50 

----------------
Test Diagnostic:
----------------
  2×1 timetable

            Time            Data
    ____________________    ____

    20-Oct-2017 00:00:00     20 
    21-Oct-2017 00:00:00     20 

---------------------
Framework Diagnostic:
---------------------
verifyReturnsTrue failed.
--> The function handle did not evaluate to "true".
--> Returned value:
          logical

           0

Evaluated Function:
  function_handle with value:

    @()isequaln(actual,expected)
>>
```

***/EDIT***

Depending on what datatypes you are working with (and which release of MATLAB) `verifyEqual` should give you what you want.

Are these arrays of type double? If so `verifyEqual` should be all you need (and will give you better diagnostics than your workaround).

If `verifyEqual` doesn't work, can you let me know which version of MATLAB you are using and the `verifyEqual` call that doesn't do what you are looking for?

Comment: I am comparing timetables with 2017a. I think verifyEqual works with arrays (and tables?) but not with timetables.